# Debugging on Windows 98: Get code line from EIP

Tags: c, debugging, dos, windows-98

I am coding in Windows 98(DOS mode) and my program is crashing badly. I can reproduce the crash just fine, but my normal debugging tricks(stack trace, printf the whole thing to isolate the crash) are failing, because the combination of graphics mode(VBE), DOS mode and interrupt handling is apparently not what GDB was made for.

I've tried commenting parts of my code to isolate the problem but I can not trace the code location of the crash exactly.

So all I can get is a bunch of registers. Is there any way to retrieve a line of code from registers(like EIP)? I am coding in C.

Comment: I think the trick is to remove Windows 98 from your machine immediately ;D

Comment: From what year are you posting this?

Comment: @astander 2010, but it doesn't feel like it. @William R Windows 7 doesn't allow unprivileged programs to mess with interrupts and BIOS calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found some [GDB documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_14.html) with this:

> info symbol addr

Using this command seems to be the closest thing I could find to get a function name from an address. It won't give the exact line of code, but it's better than nothing.